ValueError: no field of name when loading .mat file using python and scipy.io
I am attempting to load a .mat file containing a number of structures, each of which has numerous fields, using Python and Scipy.io and loadmat().  When I attempt to load the entire file, I am met with a ValueError: no field of name error.
I have attempted to load each top-level struct individually using the variable_names parameter and have narrowed the issue down to those structs containing fields that include structs without a name associated.
Fields within the BottomTrack struct
The error I get is the following:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[70], line 4
      1 # mat=spio.loadmat("C:/Users/mthom/Desktop/test.mat", variable_names=['Transformation_Matrices'], struct_as_record=True)# load mat-file
      2 # mat=spio.loadmat("C:/Users/mthom/Desktop/test.mat")# load mat-file
      3 # mat=spio.loadmat("C:/Users/mthom/Desktop/ADCP Files/01-Transect_test2.mat")
----> 4 mat=spio.loadmat("C:/Users/mthom/Desktop/ADCP Files/test.mat", variable_names=['WaterTrack'])

File c:\Users\mthom\anaconda3\envs\cs7643-project\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\_mio.py:226, in loadmat(file_name, mdict, appendmat, **kwargs)
    224 with _open_file_context(file_name, appendmat) as f:
    225     MR, _ = mat_reader_factory(f, **kwargs)
--> 226     matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
    228 if mdict is not None:
    229     mdict.update(matfile_dict)

File c:\Users\mthom\anaconda3\envs\cs7643-project\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\_mio5.py:332, in MatFile5Reader.get_variables(self, variable_names)
    330     continue
    331 try:
--> 332     res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
    333 except MatReadError as err:
    334     warnings.warn(
    335         'Unreadable variable "%s", because "%s"' %
    336         (name, err),
    337         Warning, stacklevel=2)
...
File _mio5_utils.pyx:719, in scipy.io.matlab._mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header()

File _mio5_utils.pyx:963, in scipy.io.matlab._mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_struct()

ValueError: no field of name 

Is there any way of dealing with this?  Alternatively, is there a way to load only specific structure fields using loadmat(), so I can still access a specific field, say 'Sample_Number', within the above structure example without running into this error?
EDIT:
I am unfamiliar with MatLAB files, so excuse my incorrect terminology.  The file I have is generated by an instrument, so I am unsure as to how to recreate this.  I would like to load the values in a specific field (BT_Vel) that is within one workspace (BottomTrack) within the file.  I have no issue loading other workspaces and parsing the data within each field, however I am finding that when the workspace includes fields that are structs, like shown in the screenshot linked above, where the struct includes a field showing no name, I get an error and am unable to load anything from that workspace. When I inspect the field in MatLAB, it says 'The variable...does not exist'.
Variable Does Not Exist

Does #2 (without variable names) work? If so, load it and determine what variables there are in file.  My guess is you get the errors because the names are different from what you think (or want).

There's a difference between variable names and field names in a struct.

“structs containing fields that include structs without a name associated.” What does this mean? Can you give MATLAB code that creates such a struct, so we understand what is in this MAT-file?

So… the instrument generates an invalid MAT-file? Does the manual for the instrument explain how to read the file?

It can be open and read with MatLAB. I'm trying to write a script to get the data I need from this file using only Python.
